# WSO2 API Manager - API authentication failure - Required OAuth credentials not provided

Tags: oauth, wso2

I am using wso2 API manager over one of the rest APIs we have . Every time I hit the service on wso2, I am getting the below mentioned error though the application is running fine. I have tried setting OPTIONS as "None" but in vain.
Can someone suggest how to fix it?

2014-03-25 19:36:05,647 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-9] ERROR APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APISecurityException: Required OAuth credentials not provided
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.oauth.OAuthAuthenticator.authenticate(OAuthAuthenticator.java:114)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler.handleRequest(APIAuthenticationHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:336)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:377)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error it seems you are not sending the Authorization header. Can you specify which client you are using to send the request?

Comment: I was sending the auth header but issue was occurring due to some configuration issue at the system. It has been resolved now.